# Magento 2 : After upgrade to Magento 2.2.8 version

Tags: magento2

> Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection::addIsSaleableAttributeToFilter()

Comment: why update to 2.2.8 when 2.2.10 was released recently. also this is a know issue. there is a github issue.

Comment: upgrade from 2.2.8 to 2.3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Search Your code:**

Find this Line - `$collection->addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', 1, 'left')`

and replace this with - `addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', [1], 'left')`

Hope this will help You!!